# Why my #selector is not working?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, selector

I have a function:

```
 @objc func handleLongPress(data: SkelbimasModel, _ gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer){
    if gestureRecognizer.state != .began{
        return
    }

    let touchPoint:CGPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.Map)
    let touchMapCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D =
        self.Map.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: self.Map)

    let annot:MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annot.coordinate = touchMapCoordinate

    self.resetTracking()
    self.Map.addAnnotation(annot)
    skelbimai.append(annot)
    print(skelbimai)
    self.Map.removeGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    Label.isHidden = true
}
```

My SkelbimbasModel inherits NSObject :

class SkelbimasModel: NSObject {...}

And that function is not being called :

```
func addLongPressGesture(){
    let longPressRecogniser:UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target:self , action:#selector(ViewController.handleLongPress(data:_:)))
    longPressRecogniser.minimumPressDuration = 0.5 //user needs to press for 1 seconds
    self.Map.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecogniser)
}
```

When i remove SkelbimasModel property from function like :

@objc func handleLongPress(_ gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer)

works fine. How to declare function to selector, to pass SkalbimasModel property?

Comment: Your gesture just send the `UIGestureRecognizer ` object to your function, it cannot send `SkelbimasModel `, probably thats why your function doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Selector signature must be one of the following.

```
@IBAction func myActionMethod()
@IBAction func myActionMethod(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer)
```

**Official Documentation**

> A gesture recognizer has one or more target-action pairs associated
>   with it. If there are multiple target-action pairs, they are discrete,
>   and not cumulative. Recognition of a gesture results in the dispatch
>   of an action message to a target for each of the associated pairs. The
>   action methods invoked must conform to one of the following
>   signatures:
>
> @IBAction func myActionMethod()
>
> @IBAction func myActionMethod(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer)

You can look into view tags if you wan't to differentiate between views.

```
let tag = gestureRecognizer.view?.tag
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to your question: [UIGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer)

> UIGestureRecognizer action methods invoked must conform to one of the following signatures:

```
@IBAction func myActionMethod() 
// or func myActionMethod()

@IBAction func myActionMethod(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer)
// or func myActionMethod(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer)
```

You can pass an instance of `UIGestureRecognizer` only